# Can't change the bin width for XL histogram, using vba

Tags: excel, histogram, width, bin

I want to set the width of bins in an Excel Histogram chart to 1 in vba code. I used the macro recorder to achieve the code, but somehow that doesn't work.

When I record the macro changing the BinsType and BinWidthValue by hand, it works and I get the code below. When I run the macro the values of BinsType and BinWidthValue won't change.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
    ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).BinsType = xlBinsTypeBinSize
    ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).BinWidthValue = 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Histograms and other recently added Excel chart types (waterfall, sunburst, treemap) have limited functionality in VBA. I can't say for sure if your problem is related to this shortcoming; I avoid these charts whenever possible.

If your bin width is 1, perhaps you can make a pivot table with your data, or set up a calc range that uses FREQUENCY or COUNTIF to list counts by number. Then make a plain old column chart.

Comment: Seems a good idea Jon. Thanks!