# Excel histogram bins adjustment with VBA doesn't seem to work

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I'm trying to automatically create couple histograms for given data. The problem is that I can't change bins width with VBA. How to get around this?

(Excel Version 2210 Build 16.0.15726.20188)

I looked through the docs and tried the macro recorder and this is prototype code I came up with.

```
Sub generateHistograms()

    Dim wsTab As Worksheet
    Set wsTab = Worksheets("Tabele")
    
    With wsTab.Shapes.AddChart2(-1, xlHistogram)
        .Name = "Test"
        .Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = wsTab.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange
        .Chart.ChartGroups(1).BinsType = xlBinsTypeManual
        .Chart.ChartGroups(1).BinWidthValue = 10
        .Chart.ChartGroups(1).BinsOverflowEnabled = True
        .Chart.ChartGroups(1).BinsOverflowValue = 90
    End With
End Sub
```

Running the code line by line seems like BinsType, BinWidthValue, BinsOverflowEnabled and BinsOverflowValue doesn't do anything.

Comment: Previously - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71858935/cant-change-the-bin-width-for-xl-histogram-using-vba   Perhaps still not fixed.

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks, I didn't find question regarding this topic that is so recent. Shame that it isn't fixed.